# equivalent query for python for geospatial db in mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, geospatial

I have a mongo database like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("55068cf8d77d293a1ca8475a"), 
  "category" : "City", 
  "loc" : { "type" : "Point", 
            "coordinates" : [ 88.789167, 22.407222 ] }, 
            "name" : "rajbari" 
          }
}
```

I have created a `2dsphere` index like this

```
db.places.createIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" , category : -1, name: 1 } )
```

When I query on mongo, I am getting desired result

```
db.places.find( { loc : { $geoWithin : { $centerSphere :[ [ 88.777778, 22.432778] , 3 / 3959 ] } } } )
```

This fetches me 4 rows from the db.

I need to make a python api for this, and have written the following code

```
def get_connection():
    connection = Connection()
    db = connection[database_name]
    collection = db[collection_name]
    return collection

central_points = [float(x) for x in request.GET.get('central-points').split(',')]
level = str(request.GET.get('zoom-level'))
places = get_connection()
points = places.find( { "loc" : { "$geoWithin" : { "$centerSphere" :[central_points ,level / 3959 ] } } } )
```

This is fetching me only single row, thats too when I pass actual coordinates present in database inside `central_points`

Not able to understand what I am doing wrong

Comment: Python data structure syntax is basically identical to JSON. The problem will be in your variables. Make sure those are correct and that `<longitude>`, `<latitude>` especially are in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

There may be something wrong in:

```
level = str(request.GET.get('zoom-level'))
```

the var `level` should be int or float in your situation.

```
level = int(request.GET.get('zoom-level'))
```

Try correct that and run again.